# Pick from listbox for webdriver test suit

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have javescript inside my ruby code and it generates a listbox. I'm trying to generate automatic test suit to click on an item from the list.

I tried these and non of them are working  :

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "ui-menu-item").send_keys "User 1" 

@driver.find_element(:class, "ui-menu-item").send_keys "User 1" 

@driver.find_element(:class, "ui-corner-all").send_keys "User 1"
```

and non of them are working

Here is is code -------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
< ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="listbox" aria-activedescendant="ui-active-menuitem" style="position: relative; z-index: 1; width: 373px; top: -940px; left: 232px; display: none; ">

< li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">< a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">User 1< /a>< /li>

< li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">< a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">User 2< /a>< /li>

< li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">< a class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1">User 3< /a>

< /li>< /li>< /ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my own question !!!!!

@driver.find_element(:link, "User 1").click